# Serialize some relationships to JSON, but not all

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following problem: I am trying to serialize an object (object1) to Json using Newtonsoft.Json package. I need to be able to send it to a server. The problem is object1 has several referenced objects, some that should be created together with object1, but one of them is "read only" on the server, so it must be send as a relationship.

I am using `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject` 
Example:

```
<code>
    [DataContract]
    public class Object1
    {
        // Simple Properties
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ext_ref", Order = 1)]
        public string ExtRef { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "external_comment", Order = 1)]
        public string ExternalComment { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "internal_comment", Order = 1)]
        public string InternalComment { get; set; } 
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "object2")]
        public Object2 Object2 { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "object3")]
        public Object3 Object3 { get; set; }
    }
</code>
```

This is how I get it atm. This is fine for most of the objects, but not all:

```
{
"data": {
    "attributes": {         
        "ext_ref": "2573421",
        "external_comment": "Ext Comment",
        "internal_comment": "Internal comment",
        "object2": {
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "xx":"XX", 
                    "yy":"YY"
                },
                "id": "1",
                "type": "object2s"
            },
            "object3": {
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "xx":"XX", 
                    "yy":"YY"
                },
                "id": "1",
                "type": "object3s"
            }
        },          
    },
    "type": "object1"
}
```

Because the object2 is a "special case", where it can only be understood by the server as a link, it needs to look like this:

```
{
"data": {
    "attributes":{          
        "ext_ref": "2573421",
        "external_comment": "Ext Comment",
        "internal_comment": "Internal comment",
         "object3": {
            "data": {
                "attributes": {
                    "xx":"XX", 
                    "yy":"YY"
                },
                "id": "1",
                "type": "object3s"
            }
    },
    "type": "object1",
    "relationships":{
        "object2": {
            "data": {
                "id": "1",
                "type": "object2s"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Now my question is this: Is there an easy way of doing this?

I have tried the following:
Using the Relationship attribute from JsonApiSerializer
Changing the JsonProperty settings for the object2.id property
Deleting the object2.id

I can't help thinking there must some attribute I can use to get the desired result, but atm. I am stuck

[EDIT]
I added an example object structure

Comment: Look at [CustomConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm), [here](https://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) some example.

Comment: So I am trying to simplify this, correct me if I am wrong. you are getting a JSON string as shown in the first snippet but you want JSON string as shown in the second code snippet.

Comment: Yes. But only for one of my related objects, not all.

Comment: Just trying to [`IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the error. I am using Newtonsoft.Json to create the Json with this call:
`string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(order, Format.None,
                new JsonApiSerializerSettings {
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
                });`
The part that caused the problem was the Format.None, which made the Json come out as basic Json, and not the usual format. I changed it to null, and I got the result I wanted. Big woop, wanna fight about it?